# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list when parsing a function string that contains another function as a param

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am passing a javascript function from aspx side to execute in the page where one parameter is a function, page contains complex logic and at some point it tries to parse the callback that is a string agin to a function that causes the following error.

C# code:

```
 string urlVal = $"javascript:(CallMyFunc(\"{param1}\", \"{HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(onclickHandler)}\"))";
```

onclick handler here is a string that is another function with params

```
onclickHandler = "CallMyCloseFunc('val1', 'val2')"
```

Now when the next set of code tries to parse this to a function, this is what happens

```
new Function("CallMyFunc('FirstVal', 'CallMyCloseFunc('val1','val2')');")
```

gives the error

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
> at new Function ()
> at eval

How can we get this working?

Comment: You will need to make sure the quotations around `CallMyCloseFunc` aren't used inside of the function. Now the first quotation cuts off and val1 is read as a variable and the comma is seen as a seperate string. You will have to play around with quotations to find a solid result